# How to update PostgreSQL DB timestamp to null in Asterisk?

Tags: c, postgresql, asterisk

I use ast_update_realtime() to update to PostgreSQL DB.

```
res = ast_update_realtime("confinfo", "id", "01", "start_time", "NULL", SENTINEL);
```

But I got an error like this:

```
[Oct 20 15:44:50] ERROR[30428][C-00000000]: res_config_pgsql.c:169 _pgsql_exec: PostgreSQL RealTime: Query Failed because: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "NULL"
LINE 1: UPDATE confinfo SET start_time = 'NULL' WHERE id = '01'
                                        ^
 (PGRES_FATAL_ERROR)
```

I found the reason is "NULL", not is NULL in SQL string.
How could I correct it?

Answer (score 4):

```
 UPDATE confinfo SET start_time = NULL WHERE id = '01'
```

instead of

`UPDATE confinfo SET start_time = 'NULL' WHERE id = '01'`

So you should pass NULL without `""`

Comment: I know this, but I do not use direct via PostgreSQL, I use ast_update_realtime() with value is "NULL" string. When Asterisk convert it to SQL string, the "NULL" string is 'NULL' (single quote). How can I remove this quote?

Comment: @GSP Can you pass `NULL` without `""` like this  `res = ast_update_realtime("confinfo", "id", "01", "start_time", NULL, SENTINEL);`

Comment: The ast_update_realtime() function will end with NULL (SENTIEL is NULL). If I pass NULL without quote, I got Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @GSP Try this `res = ast_update_realtime("confinfo", "id", "01", "start_time", "(select null::date)", SENTINEL);`

Comment: I checked this way, but It is same above problem. When It adds to '(select null::date)', SQL not work.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of providing NULL value you can try put empty string like `''` or simply

```
res = ast_update_realtime("confinfo", "id", "01", "start_time", NULL, SENTINEL);
```

Comment: @GSP:- Try this: `res = ast_update_realtime("confinfo", "id", "01", "start_time", "", SENTINEL);`

Comment: I got the same error (It just changed 'NULL' to '' in SQL string).

Comment: @GSP:- I am not sure but I can think of a workaround in which you can set the default value of your column in your table as NULL like this: `ALTER TABLE MyTable
ALTER COLUMN columname DATETIME  DEFAULT NULL` and then you can simply use your query like this`res = ast_update_realtime("confinfo", "id", "01", "start_time",  SENTINEL);`

Comment: I tried your way but I got Segmentation fault (core dumped). P/S: I try to change "NULL" to "now()", It can update current time to this field.

Comment: @GSP:- Yes now() will insert the current datetime in your column.

Comment: Do you know which function in PostgreSQL can return a null timestamp?

Comment: @GSP:- Ideally NULL is inserted as NULL only when we want to insert NULL in timestamp column. In your case I am not sure why it is throwing an error.

Comment: The root cause is ast_str_set(&sql, 0, "UPDATE %s SET %s = '%s'", tablename, fieldname, value); fieldname is "start_time", value is "NULL". Format of value is '%s' (single quote). This code is common function, So I can take care it.

Comment: @wingᴇd pᴀnᴛʜᴇʀ, Because Asterisk is big open source code and this function is use in many module, I can NOT make sure to change and verify it. Another If a string field is set to not null and I remove this quote, It will get error.